# Graphical interface in swift playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoa-touch, wwdc

This year WWDC scholarship applications require people to submit Playgrounds instead of complete applications.

Can we create views and other animations just like we do it in a normal iOS app (without using the storyboard obviously)? Can we use the UIView class and SpriteKit?

When they say create a playground do they want me to make it in a way such that the user will also interact with the playground by writing code or do they want me to create a completely "App-Like" UI?
What are the other constraints in a playground? Please answer according to the latest modifications to Swift and the CocoaTouch framework.

Any other information about writing things on playgrounds will help?

The WWDC scholarship information is available here : https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/scholarships/

Comment: You can use `SpriteKit` , `UIKit`

Comment: I'm still struggling with the idea